# How to create date interval with diff in php

Tags: php, diff, intervals

i want to create age in my posting. result must be like this for example:
Just Now, **1** Minutes Ago, **1** Hours Ago, **1** Days Ago, **1** Months Ago & **1** Years ago.

```
   $datetime1 = date_create($value['date']);
    $datetime2 = date_create("now");
    $diff=date_diff($datetime1,$datetime2);
    if($diff->i >0){
      $final_date = $diff->format("%I Minutes Ago");
    }else if($diff->h >0){
      $final_date = $diff->format("%H Hours Ago");
    }else if($diff->y >0){
      $final_date = $diff->format("%Y Years Ago");
    }else if($diff->m >0){
      $final_date = $diff->format("%M Months Ago");
    }else if($diff->d >0){
      $final_date = $diff->format("%D Days Ago");
    } else {
        $final_date = "Just Now";
    }
```

my date from `$value['date']` is like this **2018-05-11 07:38:47**.

when i run with that code, result only showing in **Minutes**, not working for hours, day, etc...

Comment: $value['date']=2018-05-11 07:38:47 and  $datetime2 both are same so allways you get result on minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%Y years %m months %d days %H hours %i minutes %s seconds');
```

or if you need separately then check year first

```
if($diff->y >0){
      $final_date = $diff->format("%Y Years Ago");
    }
 else if($diff->m >0){
      $final_date = $diff->format("%M Months Ago");
    }
 else if($diff->d >0){
      $final_date = $diff->format("%D Days Ago");
    }
 else if($diff->h >0){
      $final_date = $diff->format("%H Hours Ago");
    }
else if($diff->i >0){
      $final_date = $diff->format("%I Minutes Ago");
    }
else {
        $final_date = "Just Now";
    }
```

Comment: i want to ask, is that `date_create("now");` is leading 24 Hours Format? i cant echo it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Perhaps it would be worth reading up a little bit on how [If / Else Conditionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)) work in programming. Essentially, *should any if statement return true, all the rest of the else if statements are ignored / not executed.*
2. Secondly, you should have a quick look at how [String Concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) works in PHP.

To help you out, I've gone ahead and built a working example using the methods I mentioned above:

```
// DATE
$value['date'] = "2018-05-11 07:38:47";

// HTML VARIABLE
$final_date = '';

// DATE OBJECTS
$datetime1 = date_create($value['date']);
$datetime2 = date_create("now");

// DATE OBJECTS DIFFERENCE
$diff = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

// IF DIFFERENCE IS LESS THAN ONE MINUTE, DISPLAY "Just Now"
if($diff->i == 0)
{
    $final_date = $diff->format("Just Now");
}
else
{
    // ELSE, CONCATENATE STRING FOR EACH VALID DIFFERENCE
    if($diff->i > 0)
    {
        $final_date = $diff->format("%I Minutes Ago, ");
    }

    if($diff->h > 0)
    {
        $final_date .= $diff->format("%H Hours Ago, ");
    }

    if($diff->y > 0)
    {
        $final_date .= $diff->format("%Y Years Ago, ");
    }

    if($diff->m > 0)
    {
        $final_date .= $diff->format("%M Months Ago, ");
    }

    if($diff->d > 0)
    {
        $final_date .= $diff->format("%D Days Ago, ");
    }

    // REMOVE THE FINAL ", " FROM THE STRING
    $final_date = substr($final_date, 0, -2);
}

// DISPLAY RESULT
echo $final_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime1 = date_create($value['date']);

$datetime2 = date_create("now");
$diff = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
if ($diff->i > 0) {
   echo  $min = $diff->format("%I Minutes Ago")."<br/>";
}  if ($diff->h > 0) {
    echo $hr = $diff->format("%H Hours Ago")."<br/>";
}  if ($diff->y > 0) {
   echo $yr = $diff->format("%Y Years Ago")."<br/>";
}  if ($diff->m > 0) {
    echo $mn = $diff->format("%M Months Ago")."<br/>";
}  if ($diff->d > 0) {
    echo $day = $diff->format("%D Days Ago")."<br/>";
} else {
    echo $just = "Just Now"."<br/>";
}
```